# Unable to connect to MongoDB on my local system

Tags: mongodb

I have started by mongod instance, however, while running mongo instance. Command prompt just displays "connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017" and cursor is blinking after that nothing happens.

Meanwhile, when I'm checking logs of mongod instance it displays:
"2018-07-01T17:59:50.817+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53245 #1 (1 connection now open)"

Could anyone help please me resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone who can help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is there a firewall blocking the port? you may need to create a inbound rule to unblock specific port

Comment: this should be a  comment

Comment: I tried Telnet on 127.0.0.1 27017 : It is successful.
Plus, I created inbound rule to whitelist port : 27017 for TCP connection still getting same error.

Just to add:
1. I can connect successfully remote server with compass tool
2. But I can't connect same remote server with mongo instance (same is happening here cursor is blinking for indefinite time)
3. Can't connect local server 127.0.0.1:27017 with compass tool : throwing "connection timeout error"

Comment: Anyone who can help?